# Heroku error logs L10 (output buffer overflow)

Tags: heroku

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ar6B.png

i get a ton of these error in my logs even when my dyno is offline.
does someone have any idea of where there from ?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I finally deleted and recreated the app

Comment: This only resets the log usage stats.  There are better solutions / this would last long

Answer (score 16):

I beat my head against this for months without getting anywhere with Heroku support. They just kept pointing me to the L10 error docs which I'd read (and understood). The issue in my case was that there was a drain present that was NOT from an add-on. It may have been added manually by a previous engineer? Not sure. In any case, this is how I debugged and resolved it:

Look at the L10 error message to see the drain id:

```
2021-10-12T14:58:23.642214+00:00 heroku[logplex]: Error L10 (output buffer overflow): drain 'd.89456495-cf6c-4c1b-8865-kd0238j2098' dropped 4 messages since 2021-10-12T14:57:23.753982+00:00.
```

Use the heroku CLI to inspect the drains:

```
heroku drains --json -a [app-name]
```

This will list all the drains, both from add-ons and others. In my case there was an old logmatic drain (**d.89456495-cf6c-4c1b-8865-kd0238j2098**) in there that was the source of the errors.

Manually remove the problematic drain:

```
heroku drains:remove [URL] -a [app-name]
```

Restart the dynos? Not sure if that's necessary or if you can just wait.

Heroku log drains reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains

Comment: Update Aug. 23: 
heroku drains:remove [id] -a [app-name]

Answer (score 7):

Like @wlabs said, it is probably a drains issue.  [Some people report that it could be papertrail overflowing](https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/gq7car/error_l10_output_buffer_overflow_cant_figure_out/), which is common on a free plan level.

If you don't want to remove papertrail from the app, then go into your papertrail settings and configure the log filters to cut out noise you don't care about.  Then wait for the reset on the next day.

[image: where to configure log filters]

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having the same issue,

I think there is no need to recreate the app, just contact the support and they will help you.

For my case the response was like that:

> Thank you for contacting us. I've made some changes to the backend for
> [my-app-name] and [the-stg-of-my-app] that should hopefully resolve
> things. Could you please restart your applications and then let me
> know if your logs work after this?

and it works!!